# Open PathListBoxScrollBehavior WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, expression-blend

I'm using blend 4 and vs 2010 to develop a port of an app from iPad to Windows Desktop.
I have a pathlistbox with PathListBoxScrollBehavior attached like in the carousel tutorial showed by Microsoft in the presentation of PathListBoxUtils.

My path is a open path (a line) and I don't want a infinite carousel but a path list box that go through the items but stops when comes in the last or first item. Am I being clear?

Something similar to what exist is on ios (similar to the cover flow effect too)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIWDlnvHRLw&feature=related

I know there are ways to do that but I can't find it.

Comment: Would you mind linking to the `carousel tutorial showed by Microsoft in the presentation of PathListBoxUtils` please?

Comment: you need to change the controltemplate of scrollviewer in blend.

Comment: The tutorial uses a image data set but i change to take elements from a sql server.
http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/pathlistbox/carousel.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are a check box called WrapItems. When unchecked your Path List Box won't spin infinitely. 
There are some bugs to solve yet but are specific to my project. 
Hope this solution helps you too.